# Is there a DRYer method in this controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using ROR 2.3.8.

Here's my code:

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController  
  def show
    ...
  end

  def western
    @city = City.find(params[:id])

    @spots = Spot.paginate(
      :conditions => ["(city=? or state=?) and country=? and shop_type=?", "#{@city.name}", "#{@city.name}", @city.country, "Places"], 
      :page => params[:page], 
      :per_page => 20, 
      :order => 'rating_average DESC'
      )
  end

  def middle-east
    @city = City.find(params[:id])

    @spots = Spot.paginate(
      :conditions => ["(city=? or state=?) and country=? and shop_type=?", "#{@city.name}", "#{@city.name}", @city.country, "Food"], 
      :page => params[:page], 
      :per_page => 20, 
      :order => 'rating_average DESC'
      )
  end

  def asian
    @city = City.find(params[:id])

    @spots = Spot.paginate(
      :conditions => ["(city=? or state=?) and country=? and shop_type=?", "#{@city.name}", "#{@city.name}", @city.country, "Accommodation"], 
      :page => params[:page], 
      :per_page => 20, 
      :order => 'rating_average DESC'
      )
  end

end
```

I've created `western.html.erb`, `middle-east.html.erb`, `asian.html.erb` and `_shops.html.erb`.

So the first three are basically empty, but yields the `_shops.html.erb` in order not for me to recode the view layout.

Is there a better method in writing the controller?

Thanks!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to dry this up in Rails 2.3.X is a named scope in your model.  Excessive/repeated querying in your Controller is a hint of a code smell.  If you don't believe me about this, Jamis Buck has got my back!  http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model

In your Spot model:

```
# app/models/spot.rb
named_scope :by_type, lambda { |city, type|
  {:conditions => ["(city=? or state=?) and country=? and shop_type=?", city.name, city.name, city.country, type] }
}
```

In your Cities Controller:

```
#app/contollers/cities_controller.rb
before_filter :fetch_city, :except => :show

def western
  @spots = paginate_spots("Places")
end

....

private

def fetch_city
  @city = City.find(params[:id])
end

def paginate_spots(type)
  Spot.by_type(@city,type).paginate(:page => params[:page], 
    :per_page => 20, 
    :order => 'rating_average DESC'
  )
end
```

What this is accomplishing is removing most of the querying logic out of the Controller.  This is a good thing, as it allows you to find spots by city and type in other controllers if the need arises.  Pagination is likely to be specific to your individual controller, so I tend to exclude it from the scopes inside models.  If you want to build an API, you might limit to 50 instead of 20 for example and want to sort by a different method.

Comment: Thanks. I got this error `Mysql::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT * FROM `spots` WHERE (spot_type=1,'Accommodation')  ORDER BY rating_average DESC LIMIT 0, 20` which I think `spot_type` should be equal to `"Accommodation"`. How do I fix this? Also, a `{}` is needed from `:conditions ... , type]`.

Comment: My bad, I have two `:by_type` as named_scope. Have renamed it to something else and this works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: I've fixed the synax issue you've pointed out in your comment.  It's really hard for me to debug the statement without having full information about the models.  One thing you can try is splitting the scopes into smaller ones and seeing desired results.  You can chain scopes together such as Spot.by_state_or_city(@city.name).by_country(@city.country).by_type("Accomodation") while debugging.

Comment: @Patrick Robertson, as stated above, it's my fault for not knowing there is already another `:by_type` named_scope. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: @Patrick Robertson, what if I wanna show all types? What should I put in to replace `Places` in  `paginate_spots("Places")` to show all types?

Answer (score 1):

First approach: use `before_filter`. **upd: it won't work for you** (I will leave it here for educational purposes)

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController  
  before_filter :spots_and_city, :only => [:asian, :western, :middle-east]
  def show
    ...
  end

  def western
  end

  def middle-east
  end

  def asian
  end

  private

  def spots_and_city(type)
    @city = City.find(params[:id])
    @spots = Spot.paginate(
      :conditions => ["(city=? or state=?) and country=? and shop_type=?", "#{@city.name}", "#{@city.name}", @city.country, "Accommodation"], 
      :page => params[:page], 
      :per_page => 20, 
      :order => 'rating_average DESC'
      )
  end
end
```

Second approach use `helper method`: **updated**

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController  
  helper_method :spots, :city
  def show
    ...
  end

  def western
    @city = city
    @spots = spots("Places")
  end

  def middle-east
    @city = city
    @spots = spots("Food")
  end

  def asian
    @city = city
    @spots = spots("Accommodation")
  end

  private

  def city
    city ||= City.find(params[:id])
  end

  def spots(type)
    spots ||= Spot.paginate(
      :conditions => ["(city=? or state=?) and country=? and shop_type=?", "#{@city.name}", "#{@city.name}", @city.country, type], 
      :page => params[:page], 
      :per_page => 20, 
      :order => 'rating_average DESC'
      )
  end
end
```

Third: use `Decent Exposure`

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/259-decent-exposure

In my opinion I prefer to use `helper_method` for such job.

Comment: Thanks. But in my last value for condition line, there is a specific `shop_type` for each. Do you mind to review your code?

Comment: By the way, what does the `||` do in `city ||= City.find(params[:id])`?

Comment: It is caching. checkout http://railscasts.com/episodes/1-caching-with-instance-variables

Comment: Thanks. Last question: why are you so great?

Comment: Some more info, please. It isn't seemed like an error because of helper_method

Comment: Oh, I got it. You should use types you need instead of using `type` :D. See update

Comment: I think it's the `type` that causes the problem. When I remove it, it works.

Comment: I was lazy to set each type )

Comment: The proper term for ||= is a nil guard.  The logical operator || is executed prior to Object#=() .  In this case, the nil guard does nothing.  If you were to call CitiesController#spots multiple times per request, the nil guard would prevent you from calling Spot#paginate.  You aren't though, so it's just there for kicks.

Comment: @fl00r Nice! I was wondering where Rails should get the `type` previously. Now the code makes sense. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Patrick Robertson, so are you suggesting I should just use the normal `=` instead of `||=`? In what circumstances should `||=` be used?

Comment: No it better to use `||=` in helpers. In your simple case it works just the same way as normal `=` but if code will be complicating it will be useful

Comment: It's pointless to use ||= in the context of a controller unless you call that method more than once per request, and Rails is already caching the query executed in your Nil guard after the first time you've executed it.  You're referencing a Railscast from 2007 in which Ryan Bates even indicates it is no longer necessary past Rails 1.2.

Comment: Thanks for all the clarification, @fl00r and @Patrick Robertson.

Comment: @fl00r, thanks again for your code. I have learnt much from it.